# Aspose - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I can see below "Index was outside the bounds of the array" issues while accept pdf file by aspose tool. Please help me resolve this issue.

> *An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Aspose.Pdf.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.*

Code:

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(filePath);
TextAbsorber textAbsorber = new TextAbsorber();
pdfDocument.Pages.Accept(textAbsorber);
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Accordinfg to their help site this can be caused by [not having a license](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/790361/error-when-using-accept-on-pages-textabsorber.aspx).

Comment: The problem appears to be related to input PDF file. Can you please share the PDF document, so that we can further investigate the scenario.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.